error with DGChartsDynamic package in Xcode (UIkit)
i have a trouble when i launch my app in xcode
When i run my simulator device, my app run successfully
but when i run on my real device, an iphone xs, this error occurs
No such file or directory: '/Users/trinhkiettuong/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FilmValley2-gzjkggkmbsziglgpdqpewivqovbe/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks/DGChartsDynamic.framework/DGChartsDynamic'
i checked my folder:
This is folder of simulator device
This is folder of real device
how can i fix this problem ? thanks.
i tried to uninstall dgchart package and re-install it, delete debug folder

Hi @Shillwi2593 did you found any solution for this ?
i have same issue

I uninstall package and reinstall so manytime, i think god helped me

thank you @Shillwi2593, i solved my issue using the below answer i have posted so it can save someone's time.

I had the same issue, this solution worked for me:

Uninstall Charts in Swift Package Manager.
Reinstall it and make sure only DGCharts is added to target and NOT DGChartsDynamic

Immediately after this my app worked on device without issue.

Framework '' not found
I had the same error message and i solve it by first as Jared has mentioned, Reinstall DGCharts through SPM and don't add DGChartsDynamic to the target if you're not using it. Then remove the DGChartsDynamic and - framework from the Other Linker Flags in Linking - General under Build Settings of you project target. Actually i had many of these errors after removing this i got same error for another 2 dependencies and removed them from the other linker flags also solved that issue.

when using the dynamic framework you may need to select "Embed & Sign" in your target where DGChartsDynamic is used
https://github.com/ChartsOrg/Charts/issues/5162
